# Each letter once uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

javascript function which returns an array of string in such a way that it contains all possible upper-case letters of the input string one at a time sequentially.

```js
uppercase("hello") ➞ ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

what i have tried is

```js
const helloCapital = (str) => {
  let a = [];
  for (let i in str) {
    a.push(str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1));
  }
  return a;
};
```

but it gives weird results

```js
[ 'Hello', 'Eello', 'Lello', 'Lello', 'Oello' ]
```

Comment: str.slice(1) will be always "ello" in your example.

Comment: ohh..right...how to fix and get the result

Comment: `str[i].slice(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a challenge for a course or challenges website.

If that is the case, it is really, really not cool to come here and ask for that answer.

But, since I'm already here, here it goes a working solution.

```js
const capitals = s => Array.from(s,(_,i)=>s.slice(0,i)+_.toUpperCase()+s.slice(i+1))
```

UPDATE: Explaining the code

`Array.from` works on iterable objects, such as strings, Arrays and, ArrayLike objects for example.

It calls the function you pass as the first argument on each element of the iterable, in this case, the string.

The function receives 1 element of the iterable (the **_**) and the position of that element (the **i**)

So the function is returning a concatenation of 3 things:
 * the substring of the original string from 0 to i
 * the current element of the iterable, or current character, toUpperCase()
 * the substring of the original string from i+1 to the end of the string.

Comment: it's from a competitive exam but it has already ended yesterday. i am trying from yesterday and going nowhere so...

Comment: Does this handle string of single or two characters length?

Comment: little explanation of code will be useful sir...thanks in advance

Comment: @MohammadUsman, Yes, it will work with single or double character strings

Comment: @gunal, I've added the explanation

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee, the **_** is the current element, you could name it as any variable name, I just like to use the _.

Comment: Yes, on a second look i understood,those are the two variables a map could take current element and the index. Just the syntax was new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, to work you need to concat the slice before letter with capitalized letter and with the slice after letter.

```
function capitalizeEachLetter (text) {
  return Array.from(text, (letter, index) =>
    text.slice(0, index) + letter.toUpperCase() + text.slice(index + 1)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array array map,

```js
var str = "hello";

var capitals = Array.from(str).map((e, i, ar) => {

  let r = [...ar];
  r[i] = ar[i].toUpperCase();
  return r.join('');
});

console.log(capitals)
```